# Was the spider James Bond killed a real spider?

Tags: james-bond

In one of the earlier James Bond movies, James was escaping some henchmen in a jungle. I'm not quite sure what actor it was or which movie since it's been a decade since I saw the scene, but I think it was *Sean Connery* and he was wearing a white suit. During this chase sequence, a large spider (one of those big hairy ones) crawled on his arm and James smacked it, leaving a big stain on his arm.

Was this spider a real live one?

Note: the movie was not Dr. No. I distinctly remember the main character wearing a white suit, being in the jungle in daylight, being chased by henchmen, standing still, noticing a spider on his left arm, using his right arm to slap it and leaving a big stain on his shirt like you would have from a red wine spillage.

Comment: It was Dr. No. AFAIK.

Comment: I think you may be thinking of [Octopussy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHwOSskT0-w) Roger Moore, white-ish suit, in the jungle. I can't fine the full clip just yet, but I'm sure someone will be able to

Comment: Also, whichever film it was, you could check that it has the relevant *no animals were harmed...* message. I doubt they'd squash a real one, just for a Bond film...

Comment: There's no spider I can see in the *Octopussy* chase, there is a snake and a leech (which he burns off with a lighter) though. Perhaps the OP is conflating multiple scenes/movies.

Comment: @Paulie_D I might be mixing up multiple movies. One of the issues is that I'm arachnophobic, so googling this isn't really fun...

Comment: @Paulie_D There is definitely a scene in Octopussy where 007 runs through a (man-sized) spider's web. I will see if I can dig it out the scene for people to reference.

Comment: How do you discern the "bugs" you see are either organic or plants of nefarious agents?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the scene you are describing. It is from [Octopussy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086034) - at the start of 007's escape through the jungle.

[image: 007 in the spider's web]

As others have noted (and I have no source for this), it is highly unlikely the spider was real. It would be fairly easy for the prop guys to make a simple squishable model filled with some staining liquid.

Comment: This appears to be the scene I was looking for. It's not entirely how I remembered it, but it's close enough that I'm willing to chalk that up to poor recollection. I'm hesitant to accept this answer because it still doesn't conclusively answer the core question whether that spider was real or fake.

Comment: That image is no longer available, but you can see the clip [here](https://youtu.be/JOtx3Sk5Oc0?t=100). On the blu-ray, the shot is at 1:02:07. The spider looks fairly good — but there's clearly a load of yellow goo under, which is then left behind when he brushes it off, so I agree it seems unlikely to be real.

Answer (score 4):

It was a real tarantula and Bob Simmons was used as a skin double for the close-up of the spider walking on Bond’s arm.

From [Film School Rejects](https://filmschoolrejects.com/39-things-we-learned-from-the-banned-dr-no-commentary-28e2a5335144#.u4lvhnk61)

> Production designer Ken Adam had only ?475 left in his budget to build the set in which Professor Dent is told to put a spider in Bond’s room. He went for sytlized minimalism with a grid at the top of the room that would make him look like he was trapped in a spider’s web.
>
> **A real tarantula was used in the film. Bob Simmons was used as a skin double for the close-up of the spider walking on Bond’s arm.** The shot of the spider crawling towards Connery’s face was achieved by putting the spider on glass over him. However, to keep the spider from sliding off the glass, the bed had to be angled and Connery strapped down so he didn’t fall off.

(emphasis added)

Comment: I also went with *Dr No* but the scene described by the OP does not match the "spider in the bed" sequence. Plus I don't think Connery every wore a **white suit**. Sounds more like Roger Moore.

Comment: @Paulie_D OP isn't sure about it as they watched it a decade ago. And there wasn't such scene in Roger Moore's James Bond movies.

Comment: The OP describes a jungle, an escape from henchmen and a white suit...none of which are in the sequence in *Dr No*. It was probably a quick passing second or two. Perhaps *Live and Let Die*?

Comment: There was snake in that movie. No spiders. There is no profit in making assumptions. Let the OP confirm it. (Though I'm sure it's Dr. No)

Comment: There was a leech though. As I commented above to the question, it's possible the OP is conflating multiple scenes/movies. You already have my +1 though.

Comment: No, it's not this one. It's not the scene where the spider is on a bed. The spider is veritably on the arm and he slaps it dead, leaving a large stain on his suit.

Comment: @Nzall Can you google and tell us the exact movie so we can help you?

Comment: I'm actually starting to doubt it was a bond movie. I'll do some research and come back once I know the movie.

Comment: @Nzall Even if it's not that movie you're looking for, the question is still good and being a James Bond fan, I came to know something new.